# morphia query based on single field of deeply nested object

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I want to retrieve an object, based on an id (or other single field) of an object that is nested 2 levels from the object that I want to retrieve. An example to demonstrate:

I want to find all blog posts that have been commented on by a particular user.

```
Blog
  List<Comment>
    ignoredField1
    ignoredField2
    User
      id
      name
      ignoredField3
```

Comments and Users are @Referenced by their parent objects.

After reading this post
http://groups.google.com/group/morphia/browse_thread/thread/57090ef1bd2f3e74?pli=1

I understand how i would find blogs with comments where ignoredField1/2 has a particular value, but i want to navigate further than that.

I have tried the following but because all Comment fields are compared, there is no match

```
q.field("comments").hasThisElement(new Comment(new User("name")));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to do it in a fews of steps I think:

1. Get the user's object ID

   ```
   ObjectId id = userObj.getId();
   ```
2. Get all comments with that user

   ```
   Query q = ds.createQuery(Comment.class);
   q.field("user").equal("name");
   q.retrievedFields(true, "_id"); // just get the IDs
   ```
3. Get all Blogs with those comments..

**However**, there are better ways:

1. Embed Comments rather than reference them. They don't make much sense as a standalone object. Then you can do:

   ```
   Query q = ds.createQuery(Blog.class);
   q.field("comments.user").equal("name");
   ```
2. Add a reference from Comments back to Blog - an ObjectId field called "blog" for example. Then you can do:

   ```
   Query q = ds.createQuery(Comment.class);
   q.field("user").equal("name");
   q.retrievedFields(true, "blog"); // only get the blog ObjectIds
   ```

to get all the Blog object Ids, then load them in a further step.

Comment: The first part of your answer assisted me on this occasion, thanks. As for the second valid point - i completely agree, however my real model differs in that it requires 3 levels of @Referenced objects but your suggestion has persuaded me to look into changing the model in the future.